# Login Flow using Google is Not Redirecting to Custom Consent Page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, spring-authorization-server

I am currently working with Spring Authorization Server and facing a problem where the login flow using Google is not redirecting to my custom consent page (the consent page and controller are already added in resources). Additionally, user consent is not being saved in the database, though I have a consent service available. Here are the details of my implementation and configuration:

```
        authorizationServerConfigurer.authorizationEndpoint(authorizationEndpoint -> {
                    authorizationEndpoint.consentPage("/oauth2/consent");
                    authorizationEndpoint.authorizationResponseHandler(new ConsentAuthorizationResponseHandler("/oauth2/consent"));
                    authorizationEndpoint.errorResponseHandler(new ConsentAuthenticationFailureHandler("/oauth2/error"));
                });

...
       http.oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
                                .successHandler(federatedAuthenticationSuccessHandler()));
```

ConentResponseHandler:

```
public class ConsentAuthorizationResponseHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private final String consentPageUri;

    public ConsentAuthorizationResponseHandler(String consentPageUri) {
        this.consentPageUri = consentPageUri;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = (OAuth2AuthorizationRequest) request.getSession().getAttribute("authorizationRequest");
        if (authorizationRequest != null) {
            // Logic to check if consent is needed
            // Redirect to consent page if necessary
            getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, consentPageUri);
        } else {
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

it redirects me directly to final redirect_uri with something like that:

```
https://localhost:4600/?state=BGjBBlVZP9Nu38mjlNBhTAxQVC8MkfhVhp__rQsFu44%3D&code=4%2F0AfJohXn57OtvjFAeFauoWKRn07WG_9LyzPBxatj5TYYtz4hlBAuoInxe8-1ga8zt-APT-g&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&prompt=consent
```

Am I missing something in my configuration or what should I add to make it work?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!